# Reflexive Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, isometry, vector-space-isomorphism, reflexive-space

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Then we say that $X$ is *reflexive* if the map $J:X\to X^{**}$ defined by $J(x)(f):=f(x)$ is an isometric isomorphism. Here $X^{**}$ is the double dual of $X$ and $f\in X^{*}$ which is the dual of $X$.

This is how a reflexive Banach space is defined. Now, let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space. Can we get a map $I$ not equal to $J$ above, but $I$ is an isometric isomorphism from $X\to X^{**}$? I hope it should exist since in the definition precisely $J$ is mentioned to define reflexivity.

I could not find an answer to it nor succeed to think of an example. Can someone please help me to understand this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you do this even in  two-dimensional Euclidean space?  I can.

Comment: @uniquesolution I think you did not read the question correctly. This is not a duplicate of the question in your link.

Comment: @GEdgar Well, I can do it in one dimension! :-)

Comment: @Mathguide: I kind of fail to see what you are looking for. You can define $I(x)=-J(x)$. Is that a "different" $I$ like you are looking for?

Comment: It reduces to finding a nontrivial isometric isomorphism of $X$ info itself.